# how to use MYSQL in LAN with .NET (vb.net)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin, database-connection, lan

I'm a new bee to development. I need to run MYSQL(phpMyAdmin) in LAN. 
I can run .NET appication (vb.net) and mysql on local machine. Please explain how to run MYSQL in LAN ..

My local PC connection strings

```
imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module iJob
    Public MyConnection As New MySqlConnection
 Function Connection() As MySqlConnection
    'Connect Database
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = "LocalHost;" _
     & "user id=;" _
     & "password=;" _
     & "database=;"
    '
        MyConnection.Open()
        Return MyConnection
 End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Which server do you , I mean IIS or Apache? especially on the server/machine where mysql resides

Comment: Dear skv,  i have 2 pc , 1 pc(windows 7) which i install wamp server (php myadmin) and run vb.net application using above connection string. now i want to run application in second pc(windows) using same database . Please explain what to do . ..